# List and dictionary comparison

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list and a dictionary with specific items. If the item exist in the dictionary and it is on the list as well, increment the key values of that item inside the dictionary:

I am trying to print out unknown item if the item does not exist in the dictionary:

```
def take_inventory() :
    items = ['shoes','hats','shoes', 'hats','coats','gloves','dresses',
             'shoes', 'hats', 'hats','rings'] 

    emptInvtentory = {'shoes': 0, 'coats':0, 'dresses':0, 'hats':0 }
 
    for key in emptInvtentory:
        for i in items:
            if i == key:
                emptInvtentory[key] +=1
 
    for key, value in emptInvtentory.items():
        print("current stock of {0} is {1}".format(key,value) )



if __name__ == "__main__":
    take_inventory()
```

My print out:

```
 current stock of shoes is 3
 current stock of coats is 1
 current stock of dresses is 1
 current stock of hats is 4
```

I need to print also " unknown item: gloves "

Comment: If you only iterate over emptInvtentory, you'll never see `gloves` as an item to print

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest rearanging your checks for "in dictionary" and also fix some misspellings:

```
def take_inventory() :
    items = ['shoes','hats','shoes', 'hats','coats','gloves','dresses',
             'shoes', 'hats', 'hats','rings'] 

    emptyInventory = {'shoes': 0, 'coats':0, 'dresses':0, 'hats':0 }
    unknown = set()
    for value in items:
        if value in emptyInventory:
            emptyInventory[value] +=1
        else:
            # adding it to a new set so the output is orderly
            # first all known things, then all unknown ones
            # if you want to mix and match, simply print item here
            # but you might then get multiple outputs for the same
            # unknown thing
            unknown.add(value)

    for key, value in emptyInventory.items():
        print("current stock of {0} is {1}".format(key,value) )

    for thing in unknown:
        print("Unknown item: ", thing)
     

if __name__ == "__main__":
    take_inventory()
```

Output:

```
current stock of shoes is 3
current stock of coats is 1
current stock of dresses is 1
current stock of hats is 4
Unknown item:  gloves
Unknown item:  rings
```

---

If you feel adventurous, use collections.Counter to count things for you:

```
from collections import Counter

def take_inventory(items) : 
    allowed_things = {'shoes', 'coats', 'dresses', 'hats'}
    c = Counter(items)

    for allowed in allowed_things:
        print("current stock of {0} is {1}".format(allowed,c[allowed]))

    for thing in c:
        if thing not in allowed_things:
            print("Unknown item: {0} occured {1}".format(thing, c[thing]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    items = ['shoes','hats','shoes', 'hats','coats','gloves','dresses',
             'shoes', 'hats', 'hats','rings']

    take_inventory(items)
```

Output:1

```
current stock of hats is 4 
current stock of coats is 1
current stock of shoes is 3
current stock of dresses is 1
Unknown item: gloves occured 1
Unknown item: rings occured 1
```

Answer (score 0):

simply

```
items = ['shoes','hats','shoes', 'hats','coats','gloves','dresses', 'shoes', 'hats', 'hats','rings']
emptInvtentory = {'shoes': 0, 'coats':0, 'dresses':0, 'hats':0 }
for value in items:
  if value in emptInvtentory:
    emptInvtentory[value] +=1
  else:
    print("Unknown item: ", value)  
for key, value in emptInvtentory.items():
  print("current stock of {0} is {1}".format(key,value) )
```